# Change Kendo combobox placeholder text in javascript has no effect

Tags: placeholder, kendo-asp.net-mvc

- MVC 5.2.2
- Razor 3.2.2
- Kendo MVC UI v2014.2.903

In Javascript, when I want to change the placeholder text of a ComboBoxFor, I thought I could do:

```
@model MyNameSpace.Models.Address

@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.ZipCode)
    .Placeholder("Select Zip...")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Text")
    .Suggest(true)
    .BindTo(Model.MailCodes)
)
```

the javascript I use....

```
 $("#Address_ZipCode").data("kendoComboBox").options.placeholder = "Select Postal...";
```

But this doesn't seem to affect the dropdownlist placeholder text at all.

What's the correct way do do this?

Here is my Kendo UI JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/devfingers/qy85emc8/5/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The awesome people at Telerik helped me:

$("#Address_ZipCode").data("kendoComboBox").input.attr("placeholder", "Select Postal...");